# Replacing charachter by row number in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, slice

So to practice javascript I'm making a little game and I ran into a problem that I have not idea how to solve.

I want to replace the character/letter in the word by a array or index number.
For example "letter"

```
0: l
1: e
2: t
3: t
4: e
5: r
```

So in this case I want to change 3th character to character "b" making it to be "letber"

var newStr = myStr.replace(/_/t, "b");  This approach is not optional for me, it would ruin the purpose of my game.

I also took a look into .slice and .replace options but i couldn't figure out how to use it the way I explained.

Comment: 'letter'.replace('t', 'b')
Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Substring replace character.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-JavaScript) substring(start,end) is inclusive on start and exclusive on end. So "hello".substring(1,3) will be 'el'.

```
var x = "letter"
var index = 3
x = x.substr(0, index) + 'x' + x.substr(index + 1);
console.log(x);
```

output:
letxer

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to change a character from a string. Which is a `primitive` type. Since they are immutable values you can't directly change them like `array items`.
You need to create a new string to get that working.

```js
const word = 'letter';
const changedWord = word.substring(0, 3) + 'b' + word.substring(4);
console.log(changedWord)
```